# how to avoid cascading in ssas parameters in ssrs report and load default "all" when report loads?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas

i have a ssrs report which uses ssas data source and all of the parameter in report also come from ssas data source. the problem is parameters are acting as cascading parameters. i can not have values in parameter drop-down until i select parameter from previous drop-down.

i wanted to have default value "All" selected when report loads instead of waiting for selecting first parameter and then load subsequent?

i have removed @parameters from parameter data source and now here is how my MDX looks like:

```
WITH MEMBER 

[Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Category].[Category ID].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER 
[Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Category].[Category ID].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER 
[Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Category].[Category ID].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 

SELECT 
{
  [Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
  [Measures].[ParameterValue], 
  [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
} ON COLUMNS , 

  [Category].[Category ID].ALLMEMBERS 
  ON ROWS FROM 
  ( SELECT (  [OwningEntity].[Entity ID]  ) 
  ON COLUMNS FROM 
  ( SELECT ( [Organization].[Organization] ) ON COLUMNS FROM [PerformanceScores]
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Additional data source , point your first parameter with default value "from query" to that data source - This parameter need to be on the top of the list as in SSRS order of parameters is important.
- Let me know if you got any problems.
Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. thing is my first parameters are dates ranges. i have data sources for other dropdownlist parameters and have set default value set to "All" there. problem is if i don't give default values for date ranges, dropdown parameter values doesn't load initially. but once i give some default value or provide date ranges it loads values in all subsequent dropdown parameters simultaneously. i need to have this setup at initial (when i don't have date entered already).

Comment: Hi As long as you have your data range empty this will stop the execution of the parameters as long as the first parameter will be without default value the rest will not execute - why you cant change the order of the parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Create hidden parameter with IIF statement in default value.
in IIF put dummy date - this will not execute the report but will fill all the other parameters.
IIF(yourparameter.value="",dummydate.value,yourparameter.value)
Use this hidden parameter as your "Main" data range but default value will  depend on visible parameter value in IIF statement when user can choose the range
This should work...